# PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile producing blank screen

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm trying to make a basic app with an inital login screen which will then take me to a home screen where I can then choose different pages.

I'm on a Windows 7 PC and compiling into phonegap using PhoneGap Desktop with iPhone6 and Android devices.

I've stripped back my ajax call to basics to try and resolve the issue but no joy:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { 
    $.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.42.223/server/login.php',
        data: {action : 'login', formData :   $('#login').serialize()}, 
        type: 'post',                   
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if(result.status == true) {
                alert("OK");                                
                $.mobile.changePage("/index.html",  {
                    allowSamePageTransition : true,
                    transition              : 'none',
                    showLoadMsg             : false,
                    reloadPage              : true
                });
            } else {
                alert('Logon unsuccessful!'); 
            }


        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    });                   

    return false; 
});
```

Now for the fun bit... 
[PhoneGap Desktop]
If I enter login details into the page and tap submit I get sent to a **blank** page (my header and footer still show).

[Chrome Browser on PC or Mobile]
If I enter login details into the page and tap submit I get sent to the correct page and all works fine.

[Ripple Emulator]
If I enter login details into the page and tap submit I get sent to the correct page and all works fine.

The application is structured so that on entry to index.html, is a user is not logged in (using local storage as a session holder) then he/she is redirected to /page/login.html. Once logged in they go back to /index.html where a home screen will show then their option.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem the answer is to replace
    $.mobile.changePage("/index.html",  {
                    allowSamePageTransition : true,
                    transition              : 'none',
                    showLoadMsg             : false,
                    reloadPage              : true
                });

with
     $.mobile.changePage("./index.html",  {
                    allowSamePageTransition : true,
                    transition              : 'none',
                    showLoadMsg             : false,
                    reloadPage              : true
                });